# How to fix Ubuntu 14.04 Apache PID not match?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, pid

Lately, every time I restart the server, Ubuntu always gives me a warning message of `Apache 2 PID not match`. I have to manually kill it and restart Apache 2.

I then follow the guide to check if the PID file in `/var/run/apache2` is same as the one in `/etc/init.d/apache2/apache2.conf`, but I found that there's no file in `/var/run/apache2`.

I also try to follow the steps in this [website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330047/why-is-apache-failing-to-restart-review-the-situation-by-hand)

Which says "Check if pid file path set in `/etc/init.d/apache2/apache2.conf` equals `APACHE_PID_FILE` variable exported in `/etc/init.d/apache2/envvars`." But there's no such directory of `/etc/init.d/apache2/envvars`

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What's the programming question here?

Comment: The pid file is gone. I don't know how to make one.

Comment: Right.  The question is about how to run/configure a piece of software (apache).  You aren't going to be programming any solution.  The question is more appropriate for SuperUser or Linux&Unix.